# Como fazer texto aparecer e desaparecer com Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu estou aprendendo html/css/js agora, e estou com uma dúvida que está me tirando do sério. Eu estou tentando criar um botão onde, ao ser pressionado, esconda o título (quando ele estiver a mostra) e o faça aparecer novamente (quando estiver escondido). Já tentei fazer de inúmeras formas, porém nenhuma funciona. Eu clico no botão e nada acontece. Alguma dica? **(OBS: Estou utilizando Jquery)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('h1').show()) {
        (function(){
            $('BUTTON').click(function(){
                $('h1').hide();
            })
        })
    } else {
        (function(){
            $('BUTTON').click(function(){
        $('BUTTON').text('Mostrar Olá Mundo');
                $('h1').show();
            })
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Olá Mundo</h1>
    <BUTTON>Esconder Olá Mundo</BUTTON>
    <footer>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara é só usar o método `toggle()` ele já vai dar `show/hide` a cada vez que vc clica no `button`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('BUTTON').click(function(){
    
            $('h1').toggle();
        
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <h1>Olá Mundo</h1>
    <BUTTON>Esconder Olá Mundo</BUTTON>
    <footer>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```